# How to style native DOM elements in Onsen UI?

Tags: css, onsen-ui

I'm having trouble overriding default styles in Onsen UI.

This is because native selectors have higher specificity, e.g. if I have

```
h1 { color: red; }
```

This is drowned out by the native

```
.page h1 { color: green; } /* dummy example */
```

...which leads me to write long, tedius CSS selectors.

With Onsen components (i.e. elements beginning `<ons-*`) you can use modifiers, to set custom styles.

But what about native elements?

The docs mention CSSNext, so I thought, great!, I'll just use some nesting:

```
.something {
    & h1 { color: red; }
}
```

...but no dice. It seems that, although Onsen uses CSSNext for its own components, it doesn't run your own, custom CSS sheets through it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do some changes by appending my own styles at the bottom of the onsenui.css file.

Eg.

To change the background color of a ons-page which has an id="login", I set this:

```
#login .page__background {
    background-color: #cfebdc;
}
```

To create a logo class:

```
.home-logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 10% auto;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Furthermore, you may "create" your own modifier like this (append to the onsen-css-components.css file):

```
.text-input--mymod {
    text-align: center;
    color: #00ff00;
}
```

And use it as a modifier:

```
<ons-input modifier="mymod" type="password" placeholder="Your password"></ons-input>
```

This worked well for me. Hope this gives you a better idea.
You may read more about ons elements compilation on the [docs](https://onsen.io/v2/guide/compilation.html#select-compilation)